# Align lines in HighStock

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I trying to create chart with 4 lines from data that comes from server. Data likes this:

```
[  
      [  

      ],
      [  
         [  
            1467561054626,
            5.625
         ]
         [  
            1468240074898,
            5.625
         ],
         [  
            1468240407929,
            5.625
         ],
         [  
            1468240416132,
            5.625
         ],
         [  
            1468240793293,
            9.758625000000002
         ]
      ],
      [  
         [  
            1468242942684,
            195.1725
         ],
         [  
            1468243836667,
            195.1725
         ],
         [  
            1468243849911,
            195.1725
         ],
         [  
            1468246225600,
            270.1725
         ]
      ],
      [  

      ]
   ]
```

But if time one of lines is earlier than others, then it's only shows. My code:

```js
var data = [
 [],
[ // referals
  [1467561054626,5.625],[1467561055277,5.625],[1467561055942,5.625],[1467561073180,5.625],  [1467561073628,5.625],[1468240004473,5.625],[1468240074898,5.625],[1468240407929,5.625],  [1468240416132,5.625],[1468240793293,9.758625000000002]
],[ // surveys
  [1468242942684,195.1725],[1468243836667,195.1725],[1468243849911,195.1725],         [1468246225600,270.1725]
],[]
]; // it's request that comes from server
Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    // timezoneOffset: +1,
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    style: {
                        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                        '-webkit-font-smoothing': 'antialiased'
                    },
                    renderTo: document.getElementById("chart"),
                    animation: {
                        duration: 1000
                    }
                },

                rangeSelector : {
                    selected : 1
                },

                title : {
                    text : 'Revenue stats'
                },

                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                colors: [
                    'rgb(0, 144, 197)',
                    '#feb23a',
                    'rgb(255, 68, 134)',
                    '#8dc73f',
                    '#ef5d2c',
                    '#9b56b3'
                ],

                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        maxPointWidth: 17
                    },
                    pie: {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        colors: ['#D1592C', '#DC6900', '#E2A200', '#E8C600', '#97C31B', '#F0F0F0']
                    },
                    series: {
                        lineWidth: 3,
                        marker: {
                            radius: 5,
                            symbol: 'circle',
                            lineWidth: 0,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    lineWidth: 1.5,
                                    lineColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.62)',
                                    radius: 6
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    gridLineColor: "#ddd",
                    gridLineDashStyle: "longdash",
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            color: '#ACACAC'
                        }
                    },
                    tickWidth: 0,
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    type: 'datetime',
                },
                yAxis: {
                    gridLineWidth: 1,
                    gridLineColor: "#ddd",
                    gridLineDashStyle: "longdash",
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            color: '#ACACAC'
                        }
                    }
                },

                series : [{
                    name : '1 Referals',
                    data : []
                }, {
                    name : 'Referals',
                    data : []
                }, {
                    name : 'Surveys',
                    data : []
                }, {
                    name : 'Offers',
                    data : []
                }]
            };

            window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);

            setTimeout(() => chart.reflow(), 100); // resize at load
      (function (data) { // emulating server request
             for (var index in data) chart.series[index].setData(data[index]);
            })(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhcckjgc/)

Try scroll time period and you can see how sharply draws "Surveys" line.

How get
[image]
Instead of
[image]

Comment: in primary investigation,its seems there is no data for that datetime..Is It ?

Comment: @Sagar R yes, but i can't edit data in backend

Comment: in a first chart,its showing perfect right ? so how you have done that ? with hardcoded data ?

Comment: I manually edit array and add missed data

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the question is exactly. It seems, at the moment, to be "how do I plot data that isn't there?" Where would the values in your first image come from, if not from the data itself? You need to clearly define what you want to plot, and process your data accordingly

Comment: If I understand you correctly and you would like to plot your line where you don't have points, I think that only idea is to add the data manually - or make custom function adding data there.